# Kivy: Previous screen still visible behind current (next) screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, screen

I am making a simple GUI with kivy. made twi screens but facing a problem.
PROBLEM: Previous is still visible behind the current screen.

check screenshots:

First Screen..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXhuK.png)

second screen where first screen is still visible..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zrmf.png)

main.py code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file("design.kv")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        self.manager.current = "signup_screen"

class SignUpScreen(LoginScreen):
    pass

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here, design.kv

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Label:
                text: "User Login"
            TextInput:
                hint_text:"Username"
            TextInput:
                hint_text:"Password"
            Button:
                text:"Login"
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text:"Forgot Password?"
            Button:
                text:"Sign up"
                on_press:root.sign_up()

<SignUpScreen>:
    
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text:"Welcome to Another Dimension, Bitch!"
        TextInput:
            hint_text:"New Username"
        TextInput:
            hint_text:"New Password"
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text:"Submit"
            Button:
                text:"Cancel"

<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name:"login_screen"

    SignUpScreen:
        name:"signup_screen"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you inherited your `SignUpScreen` from your `LoginScreen`, which is why the widgets of the login screen is still in the signup one. The simple solution here is to instead inherit your `SignUpScreen` from the `Screen` class:

```
class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    pass
```